# Latex: how to make some text and an equation inseparable?

Tags: latex

I mean, I want something like this:

```
.... bla blabla, the equation is:

\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
```

And I want to finally render the text and the equation together, that is, no page breaks, no figure/whatever else breaks. They have to be inseparable.

How can I do this?

Comment: This should belong to http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that they belong to the same paragraph:

```
.... bla blabla, the equation is:
%
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
```

The percent sign is the important thing here because it prevents a paragraph end. Since `\predisplaypenalty` is 10000 by default, the last line of the text will always be on the same page as the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably adapt the solution proposed [in tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/how-to-prevent-pagebreak-before-item-list) for lists.

Basically, instead of using a `\par` between your text and the equation, use a custom `\par` that prevents pagebreak.